# sed how to ignore remarked lines

Tags: sed

I have the following sed command in my script

```
sed -i "/$PARAM/s/$OLD/$BEW/g"           $FILE
```

this sed command replace the OLD value to new in the line that PARAMETER exsit

but I need also to ignore the "#" lines
how it can possible to change the sed syntax in order to ignore "#" lines?
the solution must be only with sed not by perl!

Comment: Any particular reason for rejecting Perl? (`perl -pe "next if /^#/; s/$OLD/$NEW/ if /$PARAM/"`)

Comment: in some case it not work for example on @ string

Comment: for example
 perl -pe "next if /^#/; s/@d&/new_value/ if /param5/"
this not replace the @d& with new_value
and its work with sed
if you have solution for the perl problem please I will hope that U have answer for that
THX

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

`/^[^#]*$PARAM/s/$OLD/$NEW/`

replace `$OLD` by `$NEW`, if there's no hash mark before `$PARAM`

Answer (score 1):

The `b` (branch) command should help:

```
/^#/b; /$PARAM/ s/$OLD/$NEW/g
```

---

From the manual of `sed`:

```
        b label
              Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.

        [...]
```

Comment: please explain how to add the /^#/b; to my:sed -i "/$PARAM/s/$OLD/$BEW/g"   ??

Comment: @yael: I already did. It's in the second line of my answer.